# Getting Count for concatenation value of Column 1 and Column 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get a count for a concatenation of column1 and column 2

Here is what I have done so far.

```
Select Count(*) Concat(to|| from) from Table
```

This is what my data looks like

```
to    from      rate      size  
1      11         4        lg    
1      11         4        lg
1      12         5        sm
```

I need an output that would give me a column of the concatenation of column 1 and 2 so...

```
   to    from      Count
   1     11           2  
   1     12           1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select to, from_, count( to||from_ ) 
from mytable
group by to, from_
```